# Video Background fullscreen responsive

Tags: html, css, video

How is it possible to make an video fullscreen responsive.

I've tried it with:

```css
video{
width: 100%;

}
```

And:

```css
video{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

But I've got only problems with that. I can't put stuff below the video, its too big and small screens are not full with the video ...

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLHyb.png)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gysra.png)

Comment: which player r u using?

Comment: Your second code works with youtube https://jsfiddle.net/rjvz1umo/ . But as Rohit asks, with which player are you trying ?

Comment: It's the video tag ... I guess HTML5

Answer (score 0):

You need to take margins of the body and set video to 100% width, auto height and  position relative. codepen example:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMQveO

```
body {
margin: 0;
}
video {
position: relative;
width: 100%; 
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: When its an android Browser its not repsonsive. It looks like the second screenshot

Comment: Sorry , i have no android browser to test.